# Why can't irreversible process be reversed by infinitesimal steps?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

Irreversible process is the one in which the system undergoes rapid change from initial state to the final state.

Now, if I want to reverse the state of the system, why can't be it possible? I know the final state & initial state. Is it compulsory to go through each & every intermediate states during reversal?? Why is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversible by definition means to back to the original state through exactly reversing your path. So by definition you must go through each and every step.
It is clear why you can't retrace your steps one by one, because there are non! intermediate "states" are not states of equilibrium, because rapid change (faster than the speed of information in the medium) will result in nonlinear effects and turbulence etc..
Now you can go back to the original state given by its thermodynamic variables, through another process (not reverse process), in which by definition entropy must be lost (because it must have increased during the irreversible process). You can arrange for that to happen in your specific subsystem while increasing the entropy of the total as required.

Comment: +1. Reversing has to be done so that the system has to go through all the intermediates,right?

Comment: During irreversible process, does energy get lost due to heat? Even if the cylinder and the piston is frictionless, will heat still be produced?

Comment: yes heat will be produced due to the nonlinear shock-wave traversing the gas, add to that turbulence and you get heat due to fluid friction with itself.

Comment: Sir, I've read from wikipedia that you could actually bring forth the system from the final to the initial state, but you can't reverse it since the surroudings have already changed. Now what does it mean?

Comment: this means that by bringing the system back to the initial state, the surroundings wont be back to the their initial state, exactly because in both cases (original irreversible and the going back to the initial state processes) total entropy must increase.. so you can see that you started from a state, then irreversibly went to another, then back to the original state, but the total change in entropy is strictly positive by assumption, there fore the surrounding couldn't possibly be the same

Answer (score 1):

If the process was reversible via the exact route taken to provide the current state then the creation of the initial state becomes indeterministic by definition.  This violates the conservation of information, reversibility occurs via a different path, with one path entering and exiting each state of the system in its phase space.